# Migration from .net core 2.2 to 3.0 => Authorization is executed before Authenticaton

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

A few days ago i decided to migrate my application from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0
The issue i am facing is that despite ordering the app.Use.. in the right order following [the official documentation of migrating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) in the middleware Authorization happens before authentication.

Here is my ConfigureServices method in Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(settings.AppInsightsConnection);
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
        services.AddSingleton(settings);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/users/denied")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = settings.Authority;
                options.ClientId = settings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = settings.PostLogoutUri;

                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("ccms");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");

                options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
                options.ClaimActions.Remove("auth_time");
                options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");

                options.ClaimActions.Add(new MapAllClaimsAction());

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Login");

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                };

                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });

        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); //  it validates all of requests, except for GET requests
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Permissions", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAssertion(context => PermissionGranted(context));
            });
        });
    }
```

And here is the Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
            new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        await next();
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect -vERSION 3.0.0 for Authentication and Customized policy for Authorizaton.
If i use [Authorize(Permissions)] at the controller, here is the method that getS hit before the User is authenticated at all:

```
private bool PermissionGranted(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
{
    var result = false;

    var httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    var requestPath = request.Path.Value.ToLower();
    var method = request.Method.ToLower();
    var relativePath = requestPath;

    var dbContext = new PasswordManagerContext(settings.ConnectionString);
    var userParameters = Helper.GetUserParameters(httpContext, Log.Logger, settings).Result;
    var allUrls = dbContext.PathAccess.ToList();

    var rolePermissions = dbContext.RolePermissions.ToList();
    var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Ccmsid == userParameters.CcmsId);
    var regexPath = new Regex(@"\d$");
    if (regexPath.IsMatch(relativePath))
    {
        relativePath = Regex.Replace(relativePath, @"[\d-]", string.Empty); 
    }
    var pathAccess = allUrls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RelativeUrl == relativePath && x.Method == method);
    if (pathAccess != null)
        result = dbContext.RolePermissions.Any(x => x.RoleId == user.RoleId && x.PathAccessId == pathAccess.Id);
    return result;
}
```

This authorization-authentication part is working fine in .net core 2.2
Am i doing something wrong in configuration?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what about `app.UseCookiePolicy();` try moving it after authentication.

Comment: Hm, nope still the same result :/

Comment: What uses `PermissionGranted` method?

Comment: @Eldar you can see it in  services.AddAuthorization()

Comment: With `EnableEndpointRouting = false` you've disabled EndpointRouting. So that may explain why it doesn't work. Aren't you receiving warnings about this? Your problem may be solved by removing the line.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I removed it and  i received the same result

Comment: Could you share more detailed code that could reproduce your issue?How do you know that Authorization is executed before Authenticaton?

Comment: @Rena sorry, what code can i else share?  I know because it hits my PermissionGranted method before it requires me to authenticate

Comment: How did you define `settings` and `Log.logger`?Did you redirect to login page when you send request to the controller which uses `[Authorize(Permissions)]`?